# Enable http_referer back link for own website only

Tags: php, hyperlink, back, http-referer

I created a back link using the PHP http_referer for my website. It works basically but I would like to enable it only if the referer is a page with my domain. I thought about comparing the strings from the refering page and the current page but I did not find out how it could work.

This is my code:

```
    <?php // Back link to previous page.

    // If current page has been called by a hyperlink.
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] !='') echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'">&laquo; Go back.</a>';

    // If current page has NOT been called by a hyperlink.
    else return;
    ?>
```

Can you give me any advise which PHP function I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parse the url from `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and get the hostname & compare it with your own. So the function your looking for is [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
{
    if(parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST) == $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
    {
        echo '<a href="'.htmlentities($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']).'">&laquo; Go back.</a>';
    }
}
```

Also as `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` can be set by the user its a good idea to htmlentities to stop any XSS.

A safer idea as the PHP has handled if they entered from your domain, would be to just use some javascript in place of the link to send them back.

`echo '<a href="Javascript:window.history.back();">&laquo; Go back.</a>';`

Comment: Thank you Lawrence! Your answer is very helpful. I tried parse_url before but now I know that I tried it in a wrong way.